# Package upload to pypi.org broken

Tags: python, linux, ssl, python-packaging

I have been trying to workaround the latest changes to pypi for hours, and I can't find a way to do it.  My usual method of running `python setup.py register; python setup.py bdist_wheel sdist upload` currently fails with an SSL error:

```
(py27_test) [mpenning@mudslide ciscoconfparse]$ python setup.py register; python setup.py bdist_wheel sdist upload
...
Submitting /home/mpenning/ciscoconfparse/dist/ciscoconfparse-1.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
error: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)>
```

FWIW [twine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twine) also fails with SSL errors as well.  I tried downloading the SSL PEM certificate for upload.pypi.org, but somehow `twine upload --cert ~/.certs/uploadpypiio.pem dist/*` also fails with an SSL error:

```
(py27_test) [mpenning@mudslide ciscoconfparse]$ twine upload --cert ~/.certs/uploadpypiio.pem dist/*
Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Uploading ciscoconfparse-1.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='upload.pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /legacy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
(py27_test) [mpenning@mudslide ciscoconfparse]$
```

This problem has happened to me before, but I was able to workaround the problem by manually uploading my source distro and wheel to pypi.org; however, even that method fails too (it worked as recently as Jan 29, 2018).  When I try a manual package upload, they seem to have disabled it.

[image: manual_pypi_upload]

[image: manual_api_gone]

Now it seems like I'm completely stuck with no options to fix this breakage.

### Question

Is there some way to manually upload packages to pypi that I've missed somehow?  Alternately, if there is some twine magic I've missed, I'm open to hearing it.  I'm running Python 2.7.9 on Debian 8.1 in a virtualenv.

I've got:

- pip version 9.0.1
- setuptools version 38.5.1
- twine version 1.9.1

Comment: Do you try to sync the time? Usually time problem cause by time error or your system openssl is too old.

Comment: Maybe you can set `PIP_TRUSTED_HOST` as `upload.pypi.org`. But it cannot resolve the root problem. I think it could because of your `openssl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually ssl error cause by time error. So synchroinze the time will fix it in most case.